# how to relate each execution step of my mule application to my web page

Tags: mule, esb

In my mule project I added a web part. I just wanted to ask if there is a way to track every step of the execution process of my mule application via my web page.

There is a screenshot of what i want to do.[image]

Those steps are related to my mule application. For example if the first step is executed I want to mark it in my web page. Any idea please?! I'm using Mule CE 3.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [AJAX Transport](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/AJAX+Transport+Reference) to push events from Mule to the browser displaying the execution steps.

Answer (score 0):

for enterprise edition you can use mmc(mule management console). For testing 1 month trial version available.